# Genotype - Market Card refills

Tags: untagged

In [Genotype](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/geniusgames/genotype-a-mendelian-genetics-game), do the market rows for Tools, Pea plants and Assistants refill immediately or only at the end of each round?

Comment: Can't find a link to the rules there. If you're a backer, check the print-n-play rules. (update #14)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not until the end of the round. Pg. 10 of the [rulebook](https://boardgamegeek.com/filepage/207334/genotype-rulebook-english):

> (Assistant Cards are not refilled until the end of the Round.)

And pg. 12:

> Discard the remaining Pea Plant Cards, Tool Cards, and Assistants. Refill Tool and Pea Plant Cards based on player count (see p. 3) and refill 3 face-up Assistants.

And reiterated on the "reminders and clarifications" section on pg. 13:

> Tool Cards and Pea Plant Cards are only refilled during the End of the Round Reset, not when taken.

Comment: Fantastic. I found the page 12 reference but it seemed ambiguous. The other two help it out a bit.